# Identify user plan behavior switches for subscription transaction in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a `df` identifying users and their recurring transactions in a subscription-based business model, where transactions can happen on a monthly, 3 months or 6 months cycle (every 30, 90, 180 days respectively).

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble::tribble(
        ~user_id,        ~date,      ~plan,   ~order_type,
               1, "12/23/2018",  "monthly", "acquisition",
               1,  "1/22/2019",  "monthly",      "repeat",
               1,  "2/21/2019", "3-months",      "repeat",
               1,  "5/22/2019", "3-months",      "repeat",
               1,  "8/20/2019", "3-months",      "repeat",
               2,  "5/18/2019",  "monthly", "acquisition",
               2,  "6/17/2019",  "monthly",      "repeat",
               2,  "7/17/2019",  "monthly",      "repeat",
               3,  "9/14/2018",  "monthly", "acquisition",
               3, "10/14/2018", "6-months",      "repeat",
               3,  "4/12/2019", "6-months",      "repeat",
               4,  "9/14/2018", "3-months", "acquisition",
               4, "12/13/2018",  "monthly",      "repeat",
               4,  "1/12/2019",  "monthly",      "repeat"
        )
```

Each customer (identified with a unique `user_id`) is free to start with any of those "plan" and over the course of her/his subscription, can move from one plan to the other.

My objective is to identify - with a preference on Dplyr solutions:

- User upgrades (namely, her/his first order (= acquisition) is "monthly" but the subsequent are either "3-months" or "6-months")
- User downgrades (namely, her/his first order (=acquisition) is either "3-months" or "6-months" but the subsequent are "monthly")

My desired output is:

```
df_output <- tibble::tribble(
               ~user_id,        ~date,      ~plan,   ~order_type, ~behavior_type,
                      1, "12/23/2018",  "monthly", "acquisition",            "-",
                      1,  "1/22/2019",  "monthly",      "repeat",            "-",
                      1,  "2/21/2019", "3-months",      "repeat",      "upgrade",
                      1,  "5/22/2019", "3-months",      "repeat",            "-",
                      1,  "8/20/2019", "3-months",      "repeat",            "-",
                      2,  "5/18/2019",  "monthly", "acquisition",            "-",
                      2,  "6/17/2019",  "monthly",      "repeat",            "-",
                      2,  "7/17/2019",  "monthly",      "repeat",            "-",
                      3,  "9/14/2018",  "monthly", "acquisition",            "-",
                      3, "10/14/2018", "6-months",      "repeat",      "upgrade",
                      3,  "4/12/2019", "6-months",      "repeat",            "-",
                      4,  "9/14/2018", "3-months", "acquisition",            "-",
                      4, "12/13/2018",  "monthly",      "repeat",    "downgrade",
                      4,  "1/12/2019",  "monthly",      "repeat",            "-"
               )
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this with a `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(user_id) %>% 
   mutate(behavior_type = case_when(grep("monthly", 
        rle(plan)$values[1:2]) == 1 ~ "upgrade",
       TRUE ~ "downgrade"), 
     behavior_type = replace(behavior_type, all(plan == "monthly"), NA))
```

Comment: I try to apply it in my (much bigger) dataframe, and it throws an error stating "` Column `behavior_type` must be length 1 (the group size), not 0`". I guess I don't understand what `rle` does...

Comment: @xxxvincxxx  Is there a case where some of the groups doesn't have "monthly" at all

Comment: here an export of the whole df. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pj_kLH1PCDgqwwtrOU5VuIavmkszl8o0RkGVCuW5e5U/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @xxxvincxxx  IN that case, you can have a `if/else` condition `mutate(behaviour_type = if(!"monthly" %in% plan) NA_character_ else case_when(grep("..`

Comment: I made it work as: `df %>%
  group_by(user_id) %>% 
  mutate(behaviour_type = if(!"monthly" %in% plan) NA_character_ else case_when(grep("monthly", 
                                                                                         rle(plan)$values[1:2]) == 1 ~ "upgrade",
                                                                                    TRUE ~ "downgrade"), 
         behaviour_type = replace(behaviour_type, all(plan == "monthly"), NA))
`; even tho it doesn't cover cases where first one upgrades and then downgrades ... @akrun

Comment: @xxxvincxxx. Can you. please update your post with a new example that shows the issue